# sequential execution of plotting action

Tags: plotting

I have multiple sets of ss, four plot groups, in the form of

```
ss = {aa,bb,cc,dd}
```

members of these four plot groups complement each other to accomplish `DateListPlot` with `ErrorListPlot` for two time sequence curves in the final plot. In other words, the dataset `tt` is like

```
tt = {{aa1,bb1,cc1,dd1},{aa2,bb2,cc2,dd2},{aa3,bb3,cc3,dd3},{...}}
```

The desired output is a sequence of plots resulted from

`Show[{aa1,bb1,cc1,dd1}];Show[{aa2,bb2,cc2,dd2}];Show[{aa3,bb3,cc3,dd3}];Show.....`

I would appreciate any tips on how to accomplish this feat simply and intuitively. Thanks.

Comment: `Show[#] & /@ tt`?

Comment: @Rohit ...or `Show /@ tt`?

Comment: @MarcoB Yes, thanks. I tried entering that but got a "comment too short" error. I should have just added some spaces or other text to get around that. :-)

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.

Comment: If this requires two lists, would it be